# How to determine if an event is complete using a 3rd Party API - C#?

Tags: c#, event-handling, delegates, activex, com-interop

I am currently working with a third party ActiveX control where I need to detect when an event I called from the API has completed.

Looking at the ActiveX control in VS 2008 Object browser, I call `public virtual bool MyMethod()` and there is an event `public virtual event IActiveXObject_MyMethodEventHandler SettleComplete`.

There is also a delegate `_IActiveXObjectEvents_MyMethodCompleteEventHandler()` that is part of the assembly

How would I write the code to configure my application to detect when the event from ActiveX control is complete?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a thread synchronization method in which you have an object like an event used to signal when the event is finished.

```
ManualResetEvent e = new ManualResetEvent();
e.Reset();
CallMyFunction();
e.WaitOne();
```

and at the end of the handler:

```
e.Set();
```

That is, if I understand the question correctly...